# Converting .png to .gif

Tags: r

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3PXY.png)
I was sent this code for a project and was shown the outcome (the command had to have previously ran on their computer) but when I ran the code I ran into a problem with the final line where it converts 101 .png files into a .gif. I'm receiving the error of Invalid Paramater -60 and then error 40. Does anyone know how to correct this error by chance/ what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks!

I've previously tried the commands that are commented out but still received either error 4 or 127.

```
#####
setwd('C:/Users/seabs/TrackDem')
######### Analyze images
require(trackdem)
dir <- 'images' # folder with images
allFullImages <- loadImages (dirPictures=dir,nImages=1:101)
stillBack <- createBackground(allFullImages,method='mean')
allImages <- subtractBackground(stillBack)
partIden <- identifyParticles(sbg=allImages,
                              pixelRange=c(1,500),
                              threshold=0.1,
                              select='light')
## Track particles (only take into account distance)
records <- trackParticles(partIden,L=50,R=1,weight=c(1,0,0),
                          costconstant=TRUE)


######### Plot output and counter entering/leaving particles
toty <- nrow(allFullImages)
totx <- ncol(allFullImages)
n <- dim(allFullImages)[4]

## Define 'entering' and 'leaving' regions
thresEnter <- .95
thresLeave <- .05

setwd('C:/Users/seabs/TrackDem/results')
png(file="output%02d.png", width=480, height=480) ## output folder
for (i in 1:n) {
  
  if (i == 1) {
    ## Reset counting
    totEnter <- 0
    totLeave <- 0
  }
  
  plot(allFullImages,frame=i)
  points(records$trackRecord[,i,1]/totx,1-records$trackRecord[,i,2]/toty,cex=1.2,col='lightblue')
  abline(v=thresEnter,col='orange',lwd=2,lty=2)
  abline(v=thresLeave,col='orange',lwd=2,lty=2)
  
  ## Entering particles
  enterRegion <- records$trackRecord[,i,1]/totx > thresEnter
  if (i > 1) {
    newArrival <- records$trackRecord[,i-1,1]/totx > thresEnter
    if(any(na.omit(enterRegion & (!newArrival | is.na(newArrival)) )))  {
      
      inc <- which(enterRegion & (!newArrival | is.na(newArrival)))
      points(records$trackRecord[inc,i,1]/totx,1-records$trackRecord[inc,i,2]/toty,cex=1.5,col='orange',lwd=2) # highlight entering particle
      totEnter <- totEnter + 1
      
    }
  }
  
  ## Leaving particles
  leaveRegion <- records$trackRecord[,i,1]/totx < thresLeave
  if (i > 1) {
    newLeave <- records$trackRecord[,i-1,1]/totx < thresLeave
    if(any(na.omit(leaveRegion & (!newLeave | is.na(newLeave)) )))  {
      
      inc <- which(leaveRegion & (!newLeave | is.na(newLeave)))
      points(records$trackRecord[inc,i,1]/totx,1-records$trackRecord[inc,i,2]/toty,cex=1.5,col='orange',lwd=2) # highlight leaving particle
      totLeave <- totLeave + 1
      
    }
  }
  
  text(.5,.05,col='orange',label=paste('Total entering:',totEnter))
  text(.5,.1,col='orange',label=paste('Total leaving:',totLeave))
  
}
dev.off()

## Create animation
#nstall.packages('magick')
# install.packages('animation')
# library(magick)
system("convert -delay 60 *.png animation.gif")
# system("convert *.png animation.gif")
```

Comment: Please edit and use code blocks, not images. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sounds good, its been edited! Sorry about that!